# Проблема с оптимизацией цикла

Tags: c++

Программа работает верно для небольших отрезков, но когда задается отрезок к примеру от 1 до 10000000 начинается долгий процесс перебора. Нужно что-то сделать с циклом основной программы либо с функциями.
Программа записывает бинарное представление числа, переворачивает его, и снова вычисляет число а затем находит минимальное и максимальное из таких чисел (Перебор по натуральным числам).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

string to_binary_string(unsigned int n)
{
   string result;
   string ost;
   do
   {
       ost = '0' + (n % 2);
       result = ost + result;
       n = n / 2;
   } while (n > 0);
   return result;
}

string reverse_string(string n)
{
   string n1;
   for (int i = n.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
       n1 += n[i];
   return n1;

}

int from_bin_to_int(string n)
{
   int result = 0;
   int raz = 1;
   for (int i = n.size()-1; i >=0 ; i--)
   {
       if (n[i] == '1')
           result += raz;
       raz *= 2;

   }


   return result;
}


int main()
{
   SetConsoleCP(1251);
   SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
   unsigned int int_bin, min= INT_MAX, max= 0;
   string result, binary, reverse_binary;
   int a,b;
     cout << "enter segment[a:b]\n";
     cin >> a;
     cin >> b;

     if ((a > max && b <= min) && ((unsigned int(a) == a && unsigned int(b)== b))&&(a<=b))
     {
         for (  a ; a <= b; a++)
         {
             binary = to_binary_string(a);
             reverse_binary = reverse_string(binary);
             int_bin = from_bin_to_int(reverse_binary);

             if (int_bin > max)
                 max = int_bin;

             if (int_bin < min&&min!=1)
                 min = int_bin;

         }
         cout << min << endl;
         cout << max << endl;
     }
     else
         cout << "Wrong input";

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Изложите, что *должна* делать программа, а не что она делает.

Comment: Находит минимальное и максимальное из таких чисел

Comment: Программа всегда работает верно(делает ровно то, что вы пишете).  Есть сомнения, что ваша программа не делает то, что вы хотите

Comment: Мне нужно оптимизировать цикл, т.к она начинает долго перебирать числа на больших отрезках

Comment: В чем состоит задача? Вы опять рассказываете, что надо преобразовывать в строку, и сравнивать... А надо ли? Главная оптимизация - в смене алгоритма. Без точного ТЗ, в вашем пересказе - это попытки выяснить, какой рукой держать микроскоп при забивании гвоздей, а не как лучше всего забивать гвозди! Еще раз - пожалуйста, сформулируйте задачу точно, не своими словами, а так, как она была задана вам. ДОСЛОВНО!

Comment: Реверсом натурального числа n называется такое натуральное число
n  , что запись числа n   в двоичной системе счисления получается переворотом двоичной записи числа n. Например, для n=23 в 10 системе  = 10111 в двоичной, число n реверс равно 29 (10) = 11101 .
Даны два натуральных числа a и b (a ≤ b ≤ 10 9 ). Найдите
наименьшее и наибольшее из реверсов натуральных чисел отрезка [a;b].

Comment: Очевидно, что перебор не годится. Надо смотреть, у какого из чисел больше всего единиц в конце. Ну и, соответственно, нолей. С нолями проще - это числа, кратные 2^n. С единицами - они же, минус 1. Где-то у нас на ruSO уже пробегала эта задача... Но что-то найти не выходит. Есть URL проверяющей системы?

Comment: К сожалению проверяющей системы нет, только вручную, но в любом случае спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оптимизировал)

```
unsigned int reverse(unsigned int n) {

    auto n1 = n;
    auto num_width = 0;
    while (n1) {
        num_width++;
        n1 >>= 1;
    }

    unsigned res = 0;
    unsigned current_pow = 1 << (num_width-1);
    do {
        if (n & 1) {
            res += current_pow;
        }
        current_pow >>= 1;
        n >>= 1;
    } while (n > 0);

    return res;
}
// int_bin = reverse(a);
```

Или проще:

```
unsigned reverse(unsigned n) {
    unsigned r = 0;
    for (r=n&1; n>>=1; r+=r+(n&1));
    return r;
}
```

<sub>*На корректное решение задачи поиска min/max(без брутфорса) сейчас нет времени :(*</sub>

---

В ответ @Harry:

```
unsigned rev(unsigned x)
{
    unsigned s=8*sizeof(x)-ceil(log2(x+(x&(x-1)==0)));

    x = (x & 0x55555555) << 1 | (x >> 1) & 0x55555555;
    x = (x & 0x33333333) << 2 | (x >> 2) & 0x33333333;
    x = (x & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4 | (x >> 4) & 0x0f0f0f0f;
    x = (x << 24) | ((x & 0xFF00) << 8) | (( x >> 8) & 0xFF00) | (x >> 24);
    return s ? x >> s : x;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо :)

Comment: С циклами-ветвлениями? фу... :) См. вариант у меня.

Comment: Добавил вариант с одним циклом)

Comment: Опять подмешиваете логарифмы в целочисленную арифметику? Зря-зря))

Comment: @wololo, а без цикла иначе никак) Разве что ещё 32 сдвига)